# WPF Datagrid: How to stay on the same row after pressing Enter?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Our client requests to stay on the same row after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm a cell update. Is this possible? Perhaps instead of going down, it could go one cell to the right instead?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after handling the OnKeyFown Event to ByPass the Enter key ... set another Event "OnKeyUp" and try to get Enter key and do whatever you want with that event

Answer (score 1):

Override the `OnKeyDown` method and for everything except ENTER key call the `base.OnKeyDown`

Not calling the parent class version will ensure that the default behavior of cell changing doesn't happen

Comment: Thanks Raj, I got it working. However the enter key is now not even accepting the entry. :( It is good that it stays there, but it should accept the cell update. Any idea?